# dimension of GNS representation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory

We are given a $C^*$ algebra of continuous functions $\mathcal{A}:=\{f: [0,1]\to M_2(\mathbb{C})| f(0)\text{ is diagonal}\}$. Given a positive linear functional (it is actually a state) on $\mathcal{A}$ defined by $\varphi:f\mapsto \langle f(1)e_1, e_1\rangle$ where $e_1$ is the vector $(1,0)\in \mathbb{C}^2$, I want to determine the dimension of the GNS representation corresponding to this functional.

The Hilbert space corresponding to the GNS representation is the completion of $\mathcal{A}/N$ where $N=\{f\in \mathcal{A}| \varphi(f^*f)=0\}$

It is easy to that $\varphi(f^*f)=\langle f(1)e_1, f(1)e_1\rangle=||f(1)e_1||=0$ if and only if $f_{11}(1)=f_{21}(1)=0$. I am not entirely sure how to proceed from this point. Suppose that $f$ and $0$ are not equivalent, then worst case scenario, $f_{11}(1)\neq 0$ and $f_{21}(1)\neq 0$. But we have
$$
f
-f_{11}(1)\begin{pmatrix}
t & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
-f_{21}(1)\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
t & 0
\end{pmatrix}\in N
$$
In other words, $\mathcal{A}/N$ is 2 dimensional. I am wondering if I am missing something here. What is the reason with impose the condition of $f(0)$ being diagonal?

Comment: Interesting problem.  I'm also not seeing why $f(0)$ is constrained to be diagonal.  Where'd you get the problem?

Comment: @JoshKeneda it was a problem from my exam.

Comment: I’m curious! Seems like the diagonal thing might’ve been a red herring? If you ask your instructor about it and don’t mind, lemme know what they say! You might even answer/close out your question.